# When job execution error "/hudson/model/Job/permalinks.jelly:32:48"?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When I upgraded jenkins.war, the Job can not be executed before being given "/hudson/model/Job/permalinks.jelly:32:48", do not know how to solve? (Jenkins2.0 is normal, but once you upgrade to 2.1 above will be given)

jdk: jdk1.8.0_73;
tomcat: apache-tomcat-7.0.69;

[image]

jdk: jdk1.8.0_73
tomcat: apache-tomcat-7.0.69
system:win7 64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question I should be solved, I installed the new jdk then reconfigure the environment variable
[image]

Comment: Specifically what reason I was not very clear, but I try to install a new JDK, jenkins's job to build success